# How to subscribe a common characteristic for all the slaves connected with BLED112 in Windows 10?

Tags: python, c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am able to connect multiple ST Microelectronics peripherals with Windows 10 using BLED112 and pygatt library in Python. The only thing left is that I am unable to catch a disconnected event.

Moreover, I want to subscribe for notifications for all the 5 peripherals connected to BLED112 at once. I mean i need data from all of them simultaneously.

Now, the problem here is that when i run the script, I see all of the devices in a connected state, and some start to send data to the application, but the problem is that after some seconds, the notification remains for only one or two of them..

Other devices leave their connection with the BLED112. I need some sort of reconnection scenario as well.

Things to cover:

```
Disconnection event.
Subscribing all the devices at once and receive data.
Make a persistent connection for atleast an hour, with streaming live data.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why tagging with [tag:c#] ?

Comment: Not really, I am using Python as well. But the problem is that I have to pass the data from Python exe to c#

Comment: I have done everything, just the problem is that multiple devices are not getting handled by the python script. I am using the BLED112 as well

Comment: Moreover, I wanted a direct connection with c#, if possible